# What is the better way for converting lists to dictionary for bigger data without using pandas?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary, data-structures

let's say I got data from API like

```
data = [['monday', '1:00 PM', 60 ],['tuesday', '2:00 PM', 70 ],['wednesday', '3:00 PM', 65 ]] columnNames = ["Day", "Time", "temperature"]
```

How do I easily convert it to:

```
data = {""Day" : ["monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"], "Time": ["1:00PM", "2:00PM", "3:00PM"],"temperature": [60, 70, 65]}
```

I tried this:

```
def to_dict(name, index):
    for i in range(index, data_size): 
        name.append(data[i][index])
to_dict(day, 0)
to_dict(time,1)
to_dict(temperature,2)
_list = [day, time, temperature]
dict(zip(columnNames, _list))
```

for bigger datasets what is better python way to do the above?

Comment: Well you can do it in one statement given the first two lists. `dict(zip(columnNames, zip(*data)))`  But I'm not sure if it will be so fast.

Comment: @alec but I want relevant data under each column name.
Edit - It worked !!! 
Thank you but I am still not sure about that *data thing. can you provide me reference to the docs? I wanna learn more about it

Comment: Glad it worked! `*args` is just a convenient way to unpack arguments. It would be identical to `zip(data[0], data[1], data[2])` in this example. It's useful because you don't need to know the size of the list.